# Failure to resolve NotificationListener from LavaPlayer's Javax Implementation

Tags: java, android, discord, lavaplayer

I am working on a discord bot controlled from an android app.  I am using the [JDA](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA) java discord wrapper, and the [lavaplayer](https://github.com/sedmelluq/lavaplayer) audio player.

The issue I'm getting is that when I try to call `new DefaultAudioPlayerManager()` 
I get 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/management/NotificationListener;`

From my understanding, this is caused by a class that is present at compile time, but not at runtime, the issue is I have 0 idea how to solve this.  After plenty of searching the web the only answer I could find is "it is not meant to work with android"

Anything is much appreciated.  I'm pretty stuck.

Here is the code, the error has a comment 'THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS' and is in the constructor:

```
package com.example.projectprototype.music;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.AudioLoadResultHandler;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.AudioPlayerManager;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.source.AudioSourceManagers;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.tools.FriendlyException;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.AudioPlaylist;
import com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.track.AudioTrack;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.AccountType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Guild;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.TextChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.VoiceChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.managers.AudioManager;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class musicMain extends ListenerAdapter {

private final AudioPlayerManager playerManager;
private final Map<Long, GuildMusicManager> musicManagers;
private Guild guild;
private static String playing;
private VoiceChannel chan = null;

public musicMain(Guild guild) {
    this.guild = guild;
    this.musicManagers = new HashMap<>();
    //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS V
    this.playerManager = new DefaultAudioPlayerManager();
    AudioSourceManagers.registerRemoteSources(playerManager);
    AudioSourceManagers.registerLocalSource(playerManager);
}

private synchronized GuildMusicManager getGuildAudioPlayer(Guild guild) {
    long guildId = Long.parseLong(guild.getId());
    GuildMusicManager musicManager = musicManagers.get(guildId);

    if (musicManager == null) {
        musicManager = new GuildMusicManager(playerManager);
        musicManagers.put(guildId, musicManager);
    }

    guild.getAudioManager().setSendingHandler(musicManager.getSendHandler());

    return musicManager;
}

public void setChan(VoiceChannel chan)
{
    this.chan = chan;
}

public void playMusic(String song)
{
    loadAndPlay(song);
}
public void skipMusic()
{
    skipTrack();
}

public static void setPlaying(String newSong)
{
    playing = newSong;
}

public String getPlaying()
{
    return playing;
}

private void loadAndPlay(final String trackUrl) {
    GuildMusicManager musicManager = getGuildAudioPlayer(guild);

    playerManager.loadItemOrdered(musicManager, trackUrl, new AudioLoadResultHandler() {
        @Override
        public void trackLoaded(AudioTrack track) {
            play(musicManager, track);
        }

        @Override
        public void playlistLoaded(AudioPlaylist playlist) {
            AudioTrack firstTrack = playlist.getSelectedTrack();

            if (firstTrack == null) {
                firstTrack = playlist.getTracks().get(0);
            }
            play(musicManager, firstTrack);
        }

        @Override
        public void noMatches() {
            System.out.println("Nothing found by " + trackUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public void loadFailed(FriendlyException exception) {
            System.out.println("Could not play: " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

private void play(GuildMusicManager musicManager, AudioTrack track) {

    connectToFirstVoiceChannel(guild.getAudioManager());

    musicManager.scheduler.queue(track);
}

private void skipTrack() {
    GuildMusicManager musicManager = getGuildAudioPlayer(guild);
    musicManager.scheduler.nextTrack();
    System.out.println("Skipped song");
}

private void connectToFirstVoiceChannel(AudioManager audioManager) {
    if(audioManager.getConnectedChannel() == chan)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(audioManager.isConnected()) {
        audioManager.closeAudioConnection();
        if (!audioManager.isConnected() && !audioManager.isAttemptingToConnect()) {
            for (VoiceChannel voiceChannel : audioManager.getGuild().getVoiceChannels()) {
                if (voiceChannel == chan && chan != null) {
                    audioManager.openAudioConnection(voiceChannel);
                    break;
                } else if (chan == null) {
                    audioManager.openAudioConnection(voiceChannel);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!audioManager.isConnected() && !audioManager.isAttemptingToConnect()) {
            for (VoiceChannel voiceChannel : audioManager.getGuild().getVoiceChannels()) {
                if (voiceChannel == chan && chan != null) {
                    audioManager.openAudioConnection(voiceChannel);
                    break;
                } else if (chan == null) {
                    audioManager.openAudioConnection(voiceChannel);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

````
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.projectprototype, PID: 22924
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/management/NotificationListener;
        at com.example.projectprototype.music.musicMain.<init>(musicMain.java:37)
        at com.example.projectprototype.EventChannel.setMusicChannel(EventChannel.java:179)
        at com.example.projectprototype.ui.home.HomeFragment$1.onItemSelected(HomeFragment.java:99)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:957)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:946)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:55)
        at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:910)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.management.NotificationListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.projectprototype-bDIMBcMLHygmj0yt6QQ3Vw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.projectprototype-bDIMBcMLHygmj0yt6QQ3Vw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.example.projectprototype.music.musicMain.<init>(musicMain.java:37) 
        at com.example.projectprototype.EventChannel.setMusicChannel(EventChannel.java:179) 
        at com.example.projectprototype.ui.home.HomeFragment$1.onItemSelected(HomeFragment.java:99) 
        at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:957) 
        at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:946) 
        at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:55) 
        at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:910) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
    ```
````

Comment: Attach your code

Comment: You should include the stacktrace of your error. That makes it a lot more useful.

Comment: I think neither JDA nor lavaplayer officially support android. Keep in mind that android has a very limited version of the java standard library, which might be the very reason for this issue.

Comment: Thanks Minn, I'll toss my stack trace up when I'm on my pc. But ya android seems to be the issue, JDA works just fine but Lavaplayer seems to be missing some dependencies.